# Javascript. Passing an instance of an object as an argument, inside a new operator

Tags: javascript, object, reference

So I'm trying to refactor a function that goes something like this:

```
if (typeof init_common_load_more != "function") {
    init_common_load_more = function (id) {
        fdxm.js_manager.on("fdx_loadmore_js", function () {
            component_wrapper = document.getElementById(id);
            const loader = new fdxLoadMore({
                posts_counter:
                    component_wrapper.querySelector(".posts_counter"),
                load_more_posts_url: function (instance) {
                    let post_list_obj = instance.getObject("posts_list"),
                        load_options = {
                            controller:
                                post_list_obj.dataset["load_more_controller"],
                            //...other options
                        };
                    let url = "/api/posts/load_more_posts";
                    for (option in load_options) {
                        url += "/" + option + "/" + load_options[option];
                    }
                    return url;
                },
            });
                // do things wiht the loader
        });
    };
}
```

This somehow works. The problem arises when I try to make the "load_more_posts_url" function a separate function:

```
if (typeof init_common_load_more != "function") {
    init_common_load_more = function (id) {
        fdxm.js_manager.on("fdx_loadmore_js", function () {
            component_wrapper = document.getElementById(id);
            const loader = new fdxLoadMore({
                posts_counter:
                    component_wrapper.querySelector(".posts_counter"),
                load_more_posts_url: get_load_more_url(this),
            });
        });
    };
    // do things wiht the loader
    function get_load_more_url(instance) {
        let post_list_obj = instance.getObject("posts_list"),
            load_options = {
                controller: post_list_obj.dataset["load_more_controller"],
                //...other options
            };
        let url = "/api/posts/load_more_posts";
        for (option in load_options) {
                url += "/" + option + "/" + load_options[option];
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

I passed "this" as a parameter, because sometimes writing random words makes the code work. But not this time: when I console log "instance" I'm getting some kind of default callback object instead of the new fdxLoadMore object.
How can I reference the new fdxLoadMore, in the same way it is referenced on the first version of the code, but using a separate, named function?

Comment: In the first code sample, a function reference is set as the value of `load_more_posts_url`, but in the second sample you are setting the result of function call as `load_more_posts_url`, 
most probably you can solve this by setting `load_more_posts_url: get_load_more_url` instead of `load_more_posts_url: get_load_more_url(this)`

Comment: @ZIASH You are right, this solved the issue